# adf action listener called multiple times

Tags: oracle-adf

I am facing this really stupid issue which I am unable to find a solution to. I am unable to even find a root cause of why this is happening. This is what I have:

1. I am using Jdeveloper 12c (12.1.2)
2. I have a JSFF containing some buttons with action listeners pointing to Request scope bean methods.
3. This Jsff is embedded in another parent JSFF as a declarative component and this parent JSFF is put in a BTF.
4. The application is exported as ADF Lib and used in another master application.
5. The master application has a JSF page in which the BTF from item 3 above is embedded as a region.
6. When I run this JSF page from the master application, the pages are displayed correctly, but when I click any button, on the JSFF from item 2 above, the action listener is called 5 times, not only that, this 5 number keeps incrementing whenever I click on any button on that JSFF.
7. If I create a JSF in the same application where the original JSFF was, then I don't see this issue. Its only happening if I use the original JSFF application as an ADF lib in another master application.

Any idea why this may be happening? any hints on where to look for a root cause? Not that I am using this design pattern for many more pages in my app, but the issue is happening to this just one page, so its definitely not an issue with the way I am using it. It seems like I missed some configuration or did some mistake while coding and integrating this page, but not sure what is that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No code - no go, check if you got mislink or overlapping names somewhere.

Comment: Yeah it may not possible to paste the code, as I mentioned I am unable to reproduce this with any other pages I have. I tried making the names as unique as I could but the issue still persists. What do you mean by "mislink" ?

Comment: There was a bug when listener was called multiple times when there are was a LOV on some field with NULL as current value. Could it be your case?

Answer (score 0):

Im facing the same problem and after google it I found out that the causing of this problem was the binding for the button, when I removed the binding everything works fine!